# Moving photos from iPad to hard drive

Tags: ipad

How do I move photos I loaded onto my iPad 2 from a SD card to an external hard drive using a connection kit with an USB port?  Can this be done?  Had no problem downloading photos from the SD card but can't figure out how to download from the iPad to the external hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.  You will have to offload the pictures using a PC or Mac and then copy those pictures to the hard drive.  FWIW, I don't think it's even possible to put pics back onto an SD card.